# Is there a way to syncronize cycling activities from Movescount to Runkeeper or vice versa?

Tags: accessories, software

I have used Runkeeper for years to track my cycling activities with my Smart phone.

Recently bought a pulse watch Suunto Ambit 2 that stores activities in the [Movescount portal](http://www.movescount.com/) when the watch is docked, and my question now is if there as a easy way to record activities with the watch and then synchronize or push them to both Movescount and Runkeeper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is https://tapiriik.com/ but it does not have Movescout support yet. There is voting page for new services: https://tapiriik.com/supported-services-poll

Answer (score 3):

Strava is now connected with Movescount so you can sync together your stuff via [this site](https://tapiriik.com/).

Comment: Thanks Enrico! Yes I found out a couple of days ago and this two step sync actually works really good.

Answer (score 1):

The Moveslink software that manages to download stuff from your watch and uploads it to Movescount also keeps a backup of the files on your computer. Unfortunately this is some `xml` file which is not necessarily directly compatible to other platforms. But there's help! Some nice guy wrote [ambit2gpx](https://code.google.com/p/ambit2gpx/), a tool that converts the Suunto style `xml` file to a `gpx` file that should be readable by most online services or training software suites.

If you convert the files with that tool you should be able to upload them to Runkeeper as well, even without having to upload them to Movescount before (if you don't like to do that for some reason), as Moveslink will store the files from your watch locally even if it cannot upload them to Movescount for whatever reason.

But unfortunately there does not seem to be some easy and automated way to do this yet.